# Calling PUT method from web api in mvc controller

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

I created two projects for Web API and asp.net core application.
I want to implement web api in my application.

"PUT" method from my web api:

```
    [Consumes("application/json")]
    [HttpPut]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PUT(Employee employee)
    {
        try
        {

            await employeeRepository.UpdateEmployeeByProperty(
                               employee, e => e.FirstName, 
                               e => e.MiddleName, e => e.LastName, 
                               e => e.DateOfBirth, e => e.ContactNo, 
                               e => e.EmailId, e => e.HighestQualification, 
                               e => e.TypeOfEmployee, e => e.Gender, 
                               e => e.StartDate, e => e.EndDate);
            if (await employeeRepository.SaveChangesAsync())
            {
                return Ok();
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
```

and I am calling above method in my application using below code :

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> EditEmployee(Employee employeeModel,string email,int id)
{
    var UserWithSameEmail = (Employee)null;
    if(employeeModel.EmailId!=email)
        UserWithSameEmail = _dbContext.Employee
                .Where(e => e.EmailId == employeeModel.EmailId).SingleOrDefault();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        employeeModel.UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        if (UserWithSameEmail == null)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:50822");
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employeeModel);
            HttpResponseMessage response = client
                                .PutAsJsonAsync("api/employee",json).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                 TempData["msg"] = "" + employeeModel.EmailId + " updated successfully";
                ModelState.Clear();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("EmailId", "Email Id already exists");
        }
    }
    return View("_EditEmployeePartial", employeeModel);
}
```

But when i run the application then i got an error with status code 400

```
{StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: 
System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
   Server: Kestrel
   X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B? RjpcQyBQYXJ0aXRpb25cRG9jdW1lbnRzXFRlamFzIFRyYWluaW5nXEVtcGxveWVlTWFuYWdlbWVudFN5c3RlbVxFbXBsb3llZU1hbmFnZW50LldlYlxXZWJBUElcYXBpXGVtcGxveWVl?=
   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
   Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
   Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
   Date: Sat, 27 Oct 2018 07:54:27 GMT
   Content-Length: 0
}}
```

Please help me to solve this....!!!

Comment: are the two actions running in the same api or in different applications running on different ports? If they run in the same runtime, turn your controllers into services and don't call them via network but simply inject them as service. A cleaner solution would be to outsource the body of these controller actions into services and simply call the services instead of injecting one controller in another.

Comment: that two actions are in the different projects,one from Web API and another from asp.net core application......then what should I do?

Comment: You can extract the common code (database logic) into a third project which the other two will reference. Also, have you actually stepped through with a debugger and verified the db call succeeded? Your code is masking the actual error with a general 400 error.

Comment: Well what looks fishy to me is that you are not using `await` on your `PutAsJsonAsync()`, and instead directly access the responses result. Also I strongly suggest to inject the client as a service instead of wiring everything up in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

1. As @B12Toaster said this line:

   HttpResponseMessage response = client.PutAsJsonAsync("api/employee",json).Result;
   should read

   HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsJsonAsync("api/employee",json);

Nasty deadlocks tend to happen when you use .Result;

2. You have two `return BadRequest();` statements, if you're returning 400 then is it because you're hitting one of these statements surely. You will need to debug it I guess to find out why.
3. This:

   ```
   catch (Exception)
   {
       return BadRequest();
   }
   ```

should it not be `return InternalServerError();` so that your calling application knows that something has gone wrong. You should probably log this exception somewhere as well so that you know what happened.

4. Why is this a BadRequest?

   if (await employeeRepository.SaveChangesAsync())
   {
      return Ok();
   }
   else
   {
      return BadRequest();
   }

Before you process or save data you should be checking the `Employee` to make sure the processing or saving can succeed before actually doing the saving or processing and return BadRequest straight away then should know before processing that the `SaveChangesAsync` should work. We call this validation ;-)

If you look at all these points then you're going to be much closer to finding the answer.